# Не получается считывать текущие данные с инпута по нажатию. addEventListener ругается

Tags: javascript

```
const spamCheckButton = document.getElementById('send-comment');
const comment = document.getElementById('comment');
const spamWord = document.getElementById('spam-word');
let counter = 0;
const isSpam = function (string, word, timesWord) {
   if(string.includes(`${word}`)){
       counter++;
       return false
   }
   if (counter > timesWord||counter === timesWord){

       return true
   }
};
spamCheckButton.addEventListener('click', isSpam(comment.value , spamWord.value, 3 ))
```

Comment: HTML выложите, на что 'ругается'?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const spamCheckButton = document.getElementById('send-comment');
  spamCheckButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    isSpam(comment.value, spamWord.value, 3);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы в евент добавляете не функцию, а результат ее выполнения.
Правильный вариант

```
spamCheckButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>isSpam(comment.value , spamWord.value, 3))
```

либо так

```
spamCheckButton.onclick = () =>isSpam(comment.value , spamWord.value, 3)
```